# Applied $\pi$-calculus: Name binding and if clauses

Tags: process-algebras, pi-calculus

Assume in the applied pi-calculus we have the following process:
$$(\nu n)\overline{c} \langle n \rangle.0 | (\nu n) (c(y).(\text{if n=y then P else Q}))$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are further processes.

I know that the following reduction semantic holds for the applied $\pi$-calculus (from wikipedia):
$$\overline{x}\langle z \rangle.P | x(y).Q \rightarrow P | Q[z/y]$$
where $Q[z/y]$ denotes the process $Q$ in which the free name $z$ has been ''substituted'' for the free occurrences of $y$. If a free occurrence of $y$ occurs in a location where $z$ would not be free, alpha-conversion may be required.

Do I understand correctly, that in the above example, because $n$ is already used and thus not free, we would need to rename and thus the reduction would be like so:
$$(\nu n') (\nu n) (c(y).(\text{if n=n' then P else Q}))$$

While on the other hand, in the following process:
$$(\nu n)\overline{c} \langle n \rangle.0 | c(y).(\text{if n = y then P else Q}))$$
because $n$ is not bound, we can simply perform the transaction like so:
$$(\nu n) (\text{if n = n then P else Q})$$
(and thus those two processes are also semantically different)?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you're right about the processes being semantically different. There is a small mistake in your first reduction though, you forgot to remove the c(y) once you substitute y with n':

$(\nu n)\bar{c}\langle n \rangle.0|(\nu n)c(y).(if n=y \text{ then P else Q}) \rightarrow (\nu n')(\nu n)(if n=n' \text{ then P else Q})
$